# Preforming a bitwise operation on a file input in Python

Tags: python

I was messing around with Python file inputs, and I had the idea of inverting every byte in a file of a .png, and putting it into a new file, just to see what the effect would be. My code is

```
with open("BeginningImage.png","rb") as f_to:
    with open("EndLocation.png","wb") as f_wr:
        f = f_to.read()
        f_wr.write(~f)
```

This throws the error:
`TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'bytes'`.
When I get rid of the bitwise complement, the code runs as expected. I wasn't able to find any sources in which this problem happened, sadly. Does anyone know why this error is happening, and whether I can do something to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would need to loop over the individual bytes of the file.  There's no negation operator defined for strings, since that's not a generally useful thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitwise operations work on integers not bytes. Bytes act more like strings. Each element in bytes is an unsigned 8 bit integer.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation

Something like below should work.

```
with open("BeginningImage.png","rb") as f_to:
    with open("EndLocation.png","wb") as f_wr:
        f = f_to.read()
        byts = bytes((~uint_8 for uint_8 in f))
        f_wr.write(byts)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would rather go ahead with opencv.

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("BeginningImage.png")
image = ~image
cv2.imwrite("BeginningImageInv.png",image)
```